# ln -s fails to create símbolic to a file

Tags: software-installation, gcc, symbolic-link, arm

I am trying to install arm toolchain and my programming teacher gave me instructions how to do it.
I extracted the downloaded libraries in `/opt` and I tried to create links in `/usr/local/bin` pointing to `/opt/gcc.../bin/*file`

The command he gave me:

```
sudo ln -s opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc /usr/local/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc
```

Then I checked the version with:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc --version
```

but it said that it's not installed.
I looked into `/usr/local/bin`  with midnight commander and the link was red: `!arm-none-eabi-gcc`

I checked, I wrote everything correctly. I'm thinking maybe I downloaded an incorrect version of the toolchain from the arm website.

Can someone help me? Thank you!

Comment: You want a leading `/` there. Without it, the path is relative

Comment: It solved my problem! I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a / for the first part using the opt directory. See this guide on Linux paths: [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/absolute-relative-pathnames-unix/#:~:text=An%20absolute%20path%20is%20defined%20as%20specifying%20the%20location%20of,actual%20file%20system%20from%20%2F%20directory.&text=Relative%20path%20is%20defined%20as,present%20working%20directly(pwd)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/absolute-relative-pathnames-unix/#:%7E:text=An%20absolute%20path%20is%20defined%20as%20specifying%20the%20location%20of,actual%20file%20system%20from%20%2F%20directory.&text=Relative%20path%20is%20defined%20as,present%20working%20directly(pwd)).